# О реформе русского языка

Tags: общие-вопросы

Сейчас много говорят о реформе русского языка, согласно которой, например, можно употреблять слово "кофе" в среднем роде.
А еще я слышала, что согласно этой реформе можно говорить "в разы" и "пОртфель". Неужели это правда? Насчет "в разы" я еще могу допустить - эту уродливую конструкцию сейчас употребляют сплошь и рядом, но вот "пОртфель". С чего бы?
И интересно еще знать, как практически реализуется эта реформа?

Comment: *В разы* - современная разговорная конструкция, но примерно так говорил когда-то и Менделеев :  
> Д. И. Менделеев. Заветные мысли (1903-1905)  
Они {деньги} переходят из одной страны в другую с легкостью, **во многие разы** превосходящею возможность перехода каких бы то ни было товаров, переводятся просто по телеграфному сношению, занимаются для целей одного государства в других ― словом, совсем лишены того свойства, которое присуще земле в наибольшей мере, а переделывающей промышленности хотя в меньшей, но все же совершенно полной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никакой реформы нет. Кофе среднего рода – какая же это реформа? И потом – в словарях есть помета "разговорное". И потом (тут надо проверить) эта помета в некоторых словарях появилась аж в 80-х годах! Не понимаю, почему так много шума из-за этого кофе. Мужского он рода, мужского! Но в разговорной речи *допустимо* и среднего. Лингвисты это не выдумали – ведь так говорит больше половины народа.

Про пОртфель – это вы перепутали.

Answer (score 4):

А о какой реформе-то?
Об орфографической реформе давно уже не говорят. Говорили лет десять назад - да и тогда достоверности в этих разговорах было еще меньше, чем нормативности в пОртфеле.

Лопатинский несправедливо убиенный проект реформы касался только орфографии, мест ударений и грамматического рода он никак не касался.

Ни о каких других "реформах" не слышал.

Все фонетические и большинство грамматических изменений в языке не требуют какой-то "юридической" инициативы. И просто фиксируются по факту словарями и справочниками. 
Так, разговорно-допустимая форма слова "кофе" среднего рода фиксируется наряду с формой м.р., а пОртфели и т.п., как и прежде, приводятся как неправильные, даже - грубо неправильные.
Касательно варианта "в разы" - можно спорить, что лингвисты и делают. Если до чего-нибудь договорятся, будем выполнять. Пока вариант не запрещен, но и не рекомендован.
Повторюсь, это никакого отношения к орфографической реформе не имеет.

Answer (score 2):

Слово кофе уже давно ср.р. И к реформе это никакое отношение не имеет. Сама реформа включает в себя глобальные изменения. Реформы были при Петре І, Ломоносове. Известны реформы 1917-18 гг.  Ни "п***о***ртфель", ни "в разы" в современным литературном языке не допускается и находятся за его пределами. Что касается самой реформы: кто вам такое сказал? Еще не назревается никакая реформа.